# Incense Stick vs Candle

Tags: combustion

***Not sure whether to put this on Phy or chem.. ***

What exactly happens when you light an incense stick?
[image: Inscense Stick]

How is this different from a candle, or embers for that matter?

From what I understand, a candle-flame is..... well.... basically a flame and embers are pieces of glowing hot coal or wood, but then where does the lit portion of an incense stick fit in?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smouldering

Comment: Yes, smouldering the process. It could be that I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a candle, the wax first melts, then turns into a vapor *above* the wick and the oxidation region, where the vaporized fuel mixes with air, surrounds the central, cooler region. You can demonstrate this by extinguishing a candle and [then relighting the smoke above the candle](http://geekologie.com/2012/11/the-ol-relighting-a-candle-by-lighting-t.php)... the flame will flash back to the wick. This "flash-back" can be hazardous in a lab using ether, since a nearby flame can ignite the fumes which will burn back to the ether can.

Incense, [smoldering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smouldering) cotton and similar combustion relies on thermal degradation of a solid, producing a narrow flame-front on the surface of the solid fuel. Since oxygen cannot penetrate the solid, the rate of combustion is limited. For that reason, [cotton bales burn slowly](http://westernfarmpress.com/cotton/cotton-fire-rages-round-bales-burn-gin-yard-photos#slide-0-field_images-111381) but are very difficult to extinguish, since the interior remains hot and water cannot quickly penetrate. On the other hand, [stretching a cosmetic cotton ball changes the burning from smoldering to an intense flame.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4BKQptaBsM)

Comment: Wow! never knew about flashback. So basically inscense is like a candle withless exposed surface area which causes it to burn slowly?        Or is it a decomposition reaction?

Comment: Again, candles have solid fuel converting to gaseous fuel, so the solid wax is not burning, just the mixture of fuel in air. Incense burns at the surface of the solid fuel.

Comment: An application of reducing the temperature under the combustion threshold: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/201121/stopping-an-incense-stick-from-burning/201122#201122

Answer (score 0):

Temperature is the chief difference. 500 to 800C vs 1500+ Celsius. smouldering is defined as slow, low temperature incomplete combustion, the ash layer and design of the stick depletes oxygen resulting in lack of open flame. a candle flame is hot gasses and incandescent soot particles, an incense stick has an ember which is just the wood itself becoming slightly incandescent due to temperatures in excess of 500C thus unlike metal wood cannot glow without slowly burning in the process as it’s a combustible material, you’ll notice an incense ember is not as bright as a candle flame due to a much lower temperature gradient in degrees.